# how can I make an exe file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to make launch or run file as an exe file like a.out?

I know I cant write down some command on text or something to launch with clicking a file, but I want to make an actual exe file. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279380/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file?/) by [IanMin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32543/ianmin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2018-01-10**:
What you want is generate an executable file from a source file? I didn't understand very well your question.

Could you explain it better?

In the ROS Publisher tutorial a `talker` and a  `listener` executable are created:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but I can think of two possible options.

A. You can make a bash script that runs roslaunch/rosrun. This file will be executable

B. You can make a small dedicated c++ application that runs the same command as the bash script above using the [system() function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

Why do you need this to be started by an executable file so badly?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0